# How do I print only the first 3 keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
for key, value in fre.items():
    print(key, end=', ')
```

I only want my code to print only the first 3 keys.

What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to generate indices for a sequence, with which you can `break` the loop when it reaches 3:

```
for i, k in enumerate(fre):
    if i == 3:
        break
    print(k)
```

Note that you don't need to call the `items` method if you don't need the values along with the keys. Iterating the dict itself would generate the keys.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a slice like this:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}

print(*list(d.keys())[:3], sep=', ')
# a, b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the iterator with the zip keyword to print the first 3 items.

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}

for i, (k, v) in zip(range(3), d.items()):
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for key, value in fre.items():
    print(key, end=', ')
    count += 1
    if count == 3:
        break
```

Answer (score -2):

```
third_key = list(my_dict.keys())[2]
print(third_key)
```

Comment: The question is not about printing the third key, it is about printing the first three keys.